# Can't register MEX endpoint with multiple ServiceHost instances in code

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote a class that I am using to create and open my ServiceHost instances for each service.  I want to allow them to add in a MEX endpoint.  Below is the code for the Register method which creates all the hosts.  When I later loop through the host list and call Open on all the hosts, the second host to be opened errors out with "Additional information: The ChannelDispatcher at '_THE_MEX_ADDRESS' with contract(s) '"IMetadataExchange"' is unable to open its IChannelListener."  If I remove the MEX code it runs fine and opens each host.  How do I fix this?

Edit: Added full class

Edit2: Keep in mind this is fully in code and not in app.config

```
public class ServiceHostMgr
{
    #region Constructor

    public ServiceHostMgr(string ip, int httpport, int nettcpport, bool discoverable)
    {
        _hosts = new List<ServiceHost>();
        _ip = ip;
        _httpport = httpport;
        _nettcpport = nettcpport;
        _discoverable = discoverable;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Fields

    private string _ip;
    private int _httpport;
    private int _nettcpport;
    private bool _discoverable;
    private bool _disc = false;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private List<ServiceHost> _hosts;
    public List<ServiceHost> Hosts
    {
        get { return _hosts; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public ServiceHostMgr Register(Type serviceType, Type implementedContract, string path)
    {
        string nettcpuri = "net.tcp://" + _ip + ":" + _nettcpport.ToString();
        string httpuri = "http://" + _ip + ":" + _httpport.ToString();

        List<Uri> baseAddresses = new List<Uri>();
        baseAddresses.Add(new Uri(nettcpuri));
        if (_discoverable)
            baseAddresses.Add(new Uri(httpuri));

        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(implementedContract, baseAddresses.ToArray());
        /*
        if (_discoverable)
        {
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
            // If not, add one
            if (smb == null)
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(
              ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
              "mex"
            );
        }
        */
        if (_discoverable)
        {
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

            // If not, create new one, set values, add to collection
            if (smb == null)
            {
                smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

                // add to behaviors collection
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // add service endpoint
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(
                       ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
                       MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
                       "mex"
                );
            }
        }

        NetTcpBinding nettcpbinding = new NetTcpBinding();
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, nettcpbinding, nettcpuri + "/" + path);

        _hosts.Add(host);

        return this;
    }

    public ServiceHostMgr Open()
    {
        foreach (ServiceHost h in _hosts)
            h.Open();

        return this;
    }

    public ServiceHostMgr Close()
    {
        foreach (ServiceHost h in _hosts)
            h.Close();

        return this;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is the calling code:

```
        ServiceHostMgr hostMgr = new ServiceHostMgr("localhost", 8012, 8002, true)
            .Register(typeof(IPurchaseOrderSvc), typeof(PurchaseOrderSvc), "PurchaseOrder")
            .Register(typeof(ILoginSvc), typeof(LoginSvc), "Login")
            .Open();            

        Console.WriteLine("Running...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        hostMgr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are checking to see if the behavior already exists - that's good.

But even if it does already exist - you're trying to add it again - that's your problem.

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

// assume you found the ServiceMetadataBehavior... - you set new values
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

// and now you're ADDING the already existing "smb" to the behaviors collection!
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
```

So I believe what you really want is more something like this:

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();

// If not, create new one, set values, add to collection
if (smb == null)
{
   smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
   smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
   smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;

   // add to behaviors collection
   host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

   // add service endpoint
   host.AddServiceEndpoint(
          ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
          MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
          "mex"
   );
}
```

Or if you really want to set the values of an existing behavior to your specific values, you'd have to check again before calling `.Behaviors.Add(smb);` and before `host.AddServiceEndpoint` to see whether you're dealing with an **existing** behavior (then **don't** add again!), or a new one

Comment: I tried your code and it fails the same.  I updated the code above to be the full class and its calling code with your edits and it still fails :(